# Process Pool: Zombie Process && Main Process Hung

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Using multiprocessing python module, and am getting a ton of Zombie Processes and my main application never ends.

Code is VERY SIMPLE
from multiprocessing import Pool

```
  def __name__ == '__main__':
     thread_pool = Pool(5)
     full_path = ['c:/abc/abc.json', 'c:/abc/abc1.json'] # This goes on for 30 files
     final_output = thread_pool.map(do_work, full_path)
     thread_pool.close()
     thread_pool.join()

def do_work(full_path):
  i = 0
  huge_data = json.loads(full_path)
  for element in huge_data:
     if(element['flag'] == '1'):
         i = i +1
  return ({"Total": i})
```

Comment: Is your first block in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause?

Comment: I have a thread_pool.close() && thread_pool.join() function in main, which should be doing the block...